# Configure Maven project to work through proxy

Tags: eclipse, maven, proxy

I've managed to configure the proxy settings in Eclipse and Maven, but when I run my application, the application itself can't get through the proxy. Is there a way I can configure the application proxy details as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Not in Maven. This must be done in the application or through the operating system.

Comment: When you say application cant get thru proxy, what is the error you get ? You cant download the dependencies?

Comment: Java applications need to be told explicitly how to use a proxy unless the operating system does it automatically.

Comment: @rootkonda I can download the dependencies fine, so Maven is configured correctly. I know that Eclipse and the OS are configured correctly, so I think it must be the app I'm making. When running an application created in Eclipse using Maven, the application can't reach out through the proxy to retrieve an API (API works through Postman on same machine and is open without a key (TFL).